# How do you access filesDir from non activity class in Kotlin

Tags: android, class, kotlin

I am trying to access `filesDir` from a class that is called by an activity. I always get null when I try to use `applicationContext`

What is the best way to access filesDir in this method? (Without passing through a parameter from the activity)

I have included the code below (minus imports)

```java
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val sectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)
        val viewPager: ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
        viewPager.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter
        val tabs: TabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs)
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
        
        val kin = Kin()
        kin.init() //<--Here is the call from Main Activity

    }
}
```

The class below needs to be able to access filesDir

```
class Kin : Application() {

    init {
        instance = this
    }

    companion object {
        private var instance: Kin? = null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }

    fun init() { //<-- this function needs filesDir
        Log.d("test", applicationContext.filesDir.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you put a real example in code? I mean, do you want to check the filesDir in a class that extends Application()? Or from a class that doesn't have anything to do with Android framework?

Comment: @skizo-ozᴉʞs Thank you - I just want to check the filesDir in a class that extends Application()

Comment: Please can you add what you are doing and not just the MyClass class? I want to know how you are calling this..

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Thanks for the help - I have added more details of the bare minimum. I am new to Kotlin so I appreciate the help